# Xcode 5.1.1 not loading and can't connect iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I got this error:

> The version of iOS on “---- iPad” is not supported by this
>   installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of
>   the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK;
>   which is available here.
>
> OS Installed on ----'s iPad
>   7.1.1 (11D201)

So I installed Xcode 5.1.1, I have reset my computer multiple times and I still get the same error. I am still using 5.0.2?

What do I do?

**EDIT: I downloaded xcode 5.1.1 from the appstore, tomorrow I will download from the developer website and post my result here.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try change deployment target at project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have downloaded the XCode5.1.1.dmg from the developer website and installed it, and now everything works. Something buggy about the appstore...

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  A couple things here.

1)

You say you install Xcode 5.1.1 but from your screenshot it looks like you're still using version 5.0.2.

Can you make sure of the version of Xcode you're using?

To install, simply drag and drop Xcode 5.1.1 ***over*** your older copy of Xcode 5.0.2.

2)

Click "use for development" button next to your connected device in the Xcode organizer and see what happens.

Comment: Where can i access the new and old application? there is only one xcode in the applications folder. you can see from this screenshot i have 100% installed 5.1.1 https://www.dropbox.com/s/deegdtzy7yrtg1x/Screenshot%202014-05-03%2019.21.53.png

Comment: Use Spotlight (the magnifying glass in the upper right hand corner of your screen) to find all the copies of Xcode you have on your machine.  Let me know if you find more than one. :-)

Comment: nah only one :( its such a big file to download. might download the dmg from the developers website instead of app store

Comment: Right.  Just download the "`.dmg`" from Apple and then copy that over your existing copy of Xcode and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my ipad mini, it was addressed by Click "use for development" button next to your connected device in the Xcode organizer.